# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'whois'

Tags: python-2.7, whois, pywhois

I tried to execute this code:

```
import whois
w = whois.whois('webscraping.com')
print w
```

And I got the error above.
Why?

Comment: Check if you are actually importing the package with `print whois.__file__`. That should return something pointing to your `site-packages`. Otherwise, you must be importing something in your current directory that's named `whois`.

Comment: I got this C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\whois\__init__.pyc

Comment: well that's weird. `w = whois.query('webscraping.com')` should work if you've installed the package properly. I would recommend reinstalling it and trying again.

Comment: `print dir(whois)` to see all the methods and attributes from the module. You should be able to spot `query` and such in there.

Answer (score 13):

Wrong library, solution is to remove old one and install new :

```
pip uninstall whois 
pip install python-whois
```

Comment: Thank you , the problem come from the old `whois` package.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
w = whois.query('webscraping.com')
```

Comment: And actually, w will be some kind of object :) you can check the documentation: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/whois and for instance call print w.__dict__ :)

Comment: I got the error-   'module' object has no attribute 'query'

Comment: this worked for me (also with the new `python-whois`)